# connect oracle from unix server in SAS

Tags: oracle, sas

Hi I am trying to connect to the Oracle databse from the unix server through remote submit.

How can I do that?

I have tried this way.

```
signon unixserver; 

rsubmit; 
libname orab oracle path='oracleDB' schema='xxxx';
endrsubmit;

signoff;
```

Comment: assuming your connections to the unix server are OK and your signon completes, there is nothing wrong with what you have.  Make sure tnsnames is properly defined on the Unix server.  Also, give us ERROR messages -- it will help us tell you what is wrong.

Comment: Seconding what Dom said.  Just to be clear, the Unix server has to have oracle installed on it for this to work, and won't use anything you have on your local machine for the connection - it solely occurs through the Unix server.  Otherwise your connection string seems fine.

Comment: Thank you guys., ! It was solved.. thank you very much for your inputs.

Comment: @Joe What do you mean "won't use anything you have on your local machine for the connection"?

Comment: If you're running the code in `rsubmit`, then it's running on a server, and that server needs to be able to connect to Oracle etc. - your local session (whatever the `rsubmit` is being run on) is irrelevant for that purpose.